# How to use ASCII function in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I needed help in using Spark function ASCII(sparkSQl string function) by using scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

val a = sc.parallelize(Array("Santosh","Adithya"))
select ascii('Santosh')
```

I needed ascii value of santosh and ascii value of rdd a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ascii](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@ascii(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) is part of spark-sql api and can only be used on DataFrames/Datasets.

Convert your RDD to Dataset using then use the ascii function

```
import spark.implicits._
val a = sc.parallelize(Array("Santosh","Adithya"))

case class Person(val fullName: String)
val ds = a.map(Person).toDS.selectExpr("ascii(fullName)")
ds.show
```

Comment: For string based api(like bin, bit_length etc) do we need to use case class and selectExpr

Comment: `case class` is required to create dataset (spark can infer schema easily from case classes compared to regular classes or Array). `selectExpr` is needed when you use any sql function (in this case `ascii`)